# Thread local BigInteger variable in nested Parallel.For is not processed for aggregation with standard patterns?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, aggregation, biginteger, parallel.for

I tryed to refactor a nested sequential for loop into a nested `Parallel.For` loop.
But following the recommended parallel patterns and locks, the overall result was too low compared with the sequential result.

The problem was caused by a wrong or inconsistent use of BigInteger calculation methods.

For BigInteger you need to use `++-operator` or BigInteger methods like `BigInteger.Add()`.

My sources:

- [How to: Write a Parallel.For Loop with Thread-Local Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-parallel-for-loop-with-thread-local-variables)
- [Threading in C# - Parallel Programming - The Parallel Class - For and ForEach](https://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Parallel.For_and_Parallel.ForEach)

Please find sample code below:

```
    internal static class Program
    {
        static Object lockObj = new Object();
        static void Main()
        {
            //target result: 575
            NestedLoopAggregationTest();
            return;
        }

        private static void NestedLoopAggregationTest()
        {
            BigInteger totalSequential = 0;
            BigInteger totalRecomandedPattern = 0;
            BigInteger totalAntiPattern = 0;

            const int iEnd1 = 5;
            const int iEnd2 = 10;
            const int iEnd3 = 15;

            for (int iCn1 = 1; iCn1 <= iEnd1; iCn1++)
            {
                for (int iCn2 = 1; iCn2 <= iEnd2; iCn2++)
                {
                    for (int iCn3 = iCn2 - 1; iCn3 <= iEnd3; iCn3++)
                    {
                        totalSequential++;
                    }
                }
            }

            Parallel.For(1, iEnd1 + 1, (iCn1) =>
            {
                Parallel.For(1, iEnd2 + 1, (iCn2) =>
                {
                    Parallel.For<BigInteger>(iCn2 - 1, iEnd3 + 1, () => 0, (iCn3, state, subtotal) =>
                    {
                        //Solution:
                        //for BigInteger use ++-operator or BigInteger.Add()
                        subtotal = BigInteger.Add(subtotal, 1);
                        return subtotal;
                    },
                    (subtotal) =>
                    {
                        lock (lockObj)
                        {
                            totalRecomandedPattern = BigInteger.Add(totalRecomandedPattern, subtotal);
                        }
                    }
                     );
                });
            });

            MessageBox.Show(totalSequential.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + totalRecomandedPattern.ToString() + 
        }           
    }
```

Comment: You have very high lock contention, which more than negates the benefits of multiple threads.

Comment: I would avoid parallelizing all three nested loops. Parallelizing only the outer loop should yield better performance. Also I would suggest to specify explicitly the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of the parallel operation, and not rely on the default which is -1 (unlimited) and saturates the `ThreadPool`. A reasonable value is `Environment.ProcessorCount`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: The threadpool isn't necessarily saturated because .NET attemps to intelligently select the number of threads. On my system, I measure 25 threadpool threads allocated to this processing. I have 24 logical processors on my system, so .NET selected a value very close to your recommendation.

Comment: @Eric the amount of intelligence involved in selecting the threads is surprisingly low. It's not on the level of an ant, but of an amoeba. The default setting uses all the `ThreadPool` threads that are immediately available, which are initially `Environment.ProcessorCount`, and asks for more. You can read [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72981 "ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism documentation, is the given advice correct?") GitHub issue for more details, including experimental demonstration of the default behavior.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Have a closer look at what stephantoub says in the comments (e.g. `This is an unrepresentative repro in multiple ways`). I get that you disagree with him in your GitHub issue, but he is one of the most informed authorities on this topic.

Comment: @Eric well, I am not sure about the source of Stephan Toub's statistics that disqualifies my repro as unrepresentative. Myself I've watched the C# parallel tags on StackOverflow every day for 3+ years, so I should have a quite good idea about how people use the `Parallel` APIs in practice. Anyway, here we have a specific case of doing calculations with `BigInteger`s. You could try modifying my repro by replacing the `Thread.Sleep(2000)` with a chunky loop that crunches `BigInteger`s for 2 seconds, and see whether my observations still stand, or a completely different behavior emerges.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias `I am not sure about the source of Stephan Toub's statistics` Stephen is one of the most senior Microsoft engineers working on .NET. https://github.com/stephentoub

Comment: @Eric I am well aware who is Stephen Toub. He is an extremely talented software engineer, who is also an excellent writer and communicator. But when it comes to what use of the tools is representative, meaning how people actually use the tools in practice, I am not going to discard the evidence coming from my own eyes!

Comment: @Eric btw all I am saying is: always specify explicitly the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. If you think that the default value `-1` is the best, then configure it with `-1`. The difference is that anyone who is going to maintain your code will be hinted that you made a conscious decision, instead of just trusting Microsoft's defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Your current parallel implementation requires a lock every time `subtotal` is modified in the inner loop. This modified approach is faster than both your serial and parallel implementaions because it avoids a lock in the innermost loop:

```
Parallel.For(1, iEnd1 + 1, (iCn1) =>
{
    Parallel.For(1, iEnd2 + 1, (iCn2) =>
    {
        BigInteger subtotal = 0;
        for (var iCnt3 = iCn2 - 1; iCnt3 < iEnd3 + 1; iCnt3++)
        {
            //Solution:
            //for BigInteger use ++-operator or BigInteger.Add()
            subtotal = BigInteger.Add(subtotal, 1);
        }
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            totalRecomandedPatternModified = BigInteger.Add(totalRecomandedPatternModified, subtotal);
        }
    });
});
```

I increased each of the endpoints by a factor of 10 so the runtime is long enough to be measured on my hardware, then got the following average times:

```
Serial:   9ms
Parallel: 11ms
Modified: 2ms
```

Comment: Thank you Eric, I will give your modification a try. To get a better understanding of the basic parallel techniques, I started simple refactoring without much code modifications/thread pool optimization. So far, the parallelized loops complete definitely much faster than the serial loops, but the overall completion time is still slower than hoped (far away from milliseconds). Also, the responsiveness of my code editor almost went down the drain after the adjustment to nested `Parallel.For`. Therefore I definitely need to re-think the solution and change my coding strategy.